# Moodle - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am facing the following error in moodle version 4.2.1 while creating Quiz questions. Not sure why it suddenly started happening.

Has anyone faced something similar ? A screenshot of error trace has been attached. Please check.

```
Error reading from database

More information about this error

Debug info: Subquery returns more than 1 row

SELECT allversions.id AS versionid, allversions.version,
    allversions.questionid
FROM mdlyo question_versions allversions
WHERE allversions.questionbankentryid =
    ( SELECT givenversion.questionbankentryid
      FROM mdlyo question_versions givenversion
      WHERE givenversion questionid = ?
)
AND allversions.status <> ?
ORDER BY allversions version DESC

[array (
-line 64 of /mod/quiz/classes/question/bank/qbank_helper.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->get_records_sql() 1 => 'draft',
0 => 1298,
Error code: dmlreadexception
Stack trace:
⚫ line 494 of /lib/dml/moodle_database.php: dml_read_exception thrown
⚫ line 293 of /lib/dml/moodle_read_slave_trait.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()
⚫ line 1278 of /lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->query_end())
⚫ line 64 of /mod/quiz/classes/question/bank/qbank_helper.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->get_records_sql()
⚫ line 699 of /mod/quiz/classes/structure.php: call to mod_quiz question\bank\qbank_helper::get_version_options()
⚫ line 770 of /mod/quiz/classes/output/edit_renderer.php: call to mod_quiz structure->get_version_choices_for_slot()
⚫ line 547 of /mod/quiz/classes/output/edit_renderer.php: call to mod_quiz output\edit_renderer->question()
⚫ line 520 of /mod/quiz/classes/output/edit_renderer.php: call to mod_quiz output edit_renderer->question_row()
⚫ line 95 of /mod/quiz/classes/output/edit_renderer.php: call to mod_quiz\output\edit_renderer->questions_in_section()
⚫ line 210 of /mod/quiz/edit.php: call to mod_quiz output edit_renderer->edit_page()
Continue
```

[image]

Comment: Please always post the text not a screen shot of the text

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is in the core Moodle code

In `function get_version_options()` in `/mod/quiz/classes/question/bank/qbank_helper.php`

Added by MDL-74255 in April 2022

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-74255

```
git show 839cccead412
```

Strictly speaking, this shouldn't be using a subquery

It should use the EXISTS operator, something like

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT givenversion.questionbankentryid
    FROM {question_versions} givenversion
    WHERE givenversion.questionbankentryid = allversions.questionbankentryid
    AND givenversion.questionid = ?
)
```

That would mean amending the core code though

Maybe have a look at the data to see why there is a duplicate?

```
SELECT *
FROM mdlyo_question_versions givenversion
WHERE givenversion.questionid = 1298
```

Comment: Thanks Russell. This actually worked!! I edited qbank_helper.php and the error is gone.
However, I started getting another error, where i see different version soon as i changed the version of the question. Also, I am unable to see any edited content of the questions feedback. Please check the error here: 
https://pastebin.com/zCqpsvm6

Comment: Also, here's the link of the issue video: 
https://www.loom.com/share/980038bb2bd1407db0f244129571002c?sid=294d111c-7112-4cd3-9067-34f804d2c8f3